# ReactJS rendering Component From String

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In ReactJS I am trying to render a component from a string that I dynamically create. My render function looks like this:

```
render() {
 var content = '<h1>Hello</h1>'
 content += "<Link href={'http://www.google.com'} text={'Click Here'} />
 content += '<h1>World</h1>';
return (
   <div>
     <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={content} />
   </div>
);
}
```

Except the component link is not being render and it is being printed as html. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using react-router or a custom Link component?

Comment: `Link` doesn't exist in HTML. You are telling React to treat interpret the string as HTML and that's exactly what it does.

Comment: Link is an easy example. My real code uses a custom compontent

Comment: Then you cannot tell React to treat your string as HTML. You are getting what you are asking for. JSX !== HTML. Putting JSX inside a string is the wrong approach from the start. You are saying you are creating it dynamically. How/where/why? We should find a better solution than that.

Comment: I think you may be misusing components a bit. What you can do is pass in a data object and then have a `type` prop and based on the type prop the container component will render a different child component. I am unsure as to what the exact implementation is, so if you could elaborate on that that would help, but it sounds like you are taking an adverse approach to using components. I can guarantee there is a way to do this that is idiomatic in react.

Comment: @m.a.solano The problem I am sovling is I am getting html from an api and I have to enter components into that html at certian point. Ie an ad for example.

Comment: @DevinDixon Can you post a sample response?