# ReactJS rendering appended span fromstring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a similar question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640744/reactjs-rendering-component-from-string)

I am trying to convert create a custom components where it convert each string to difference color
for example

input "A B C D"

output **A** B *C* D 
(cant chance color in this question, so I used Bolt and emphasis instead, same logic)

Currently I have

```
//In component
function MakeColor(){
  var input = [
    {letter:"A",color:"Red"},
    {letter:"B",color:"Blue"},
    {letter:"C",color:"Orange"},
    {letter:"D",color:"Yellow"}
  ];
  var output ="";
  input.forEach(function(object){
    output=output+"<span className="+object.color+">"+object.letter+"</span>";
  })
  return React.createElement('div',null,output)
}
//In another component
class Display extends Component {
   componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({letter:MakeColor();})
   }
   render(){
      <div>{this.state.letter}</div>
   }
}
//In the outer component
...
render(){
  return(
     ...
     <Display />
     ...
  )
}
...
```

This will return the text 
`<span className=Red>A</span><span className=Blue>B</span><span className=Orange>C</span><span className=Yellow>D</span>` instead of `ABCD`

Comment: Instead of having it as string have it as array, i.e `output.push(...)` push the value in each iteration instead of appending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are mixing a lot of concepts.

1. You don't need state
2. Use JSX instead of **React.createElement**, you don't need it with this case.

   function Display() {
     return makeLetter();
   }

The **makeLetter** function:

```
const LETTERS = [
  { letter:"A",color:"Red" },
  { letter:"B",color:"Blue" },
  { letter:"C",color:"Orange" },
  { letter:"D",color:"Yellow" }
];

function makeLetter() {
  return LETTERS.map((obj) => <span className={obj.color}>{obj.letter}</span>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use JSX instead?

```js
let input = [
  { letter: 'A', color: 'Red' },
  { letter: 'B', color: 'Blue' },
  { letter: 'C', color: 'Orange' },
  { letter: 'D', color: 'Yellow' }
];

let output = input.map(item => (
  <span className={item.color}>{item.letter}</span>
));

return (
  <div>{output}</div>
);
```

Or even more succinctly:

```js
let input = [...];  // As before

return (
  <div>
    {input.map(item => (<span className={item.color}>{item.letter}</span>))}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my observation:

1) You are not usings styles /css classes, neither you have used styles attribute.

So you code should be something like:

```
  var input = [
    {letter:"A",style: {color:"red"}},
    {letter:"B",style: {color:"blue"}},
    {letter:"C",style: {color:"orange"}},
    {letter:"D",style: {color:"yellow"}}
  ];
```

and also at below line, you can use JSX to return instead of a string:

```
 output=output+"<span className="+object.color+">"+object.letter+"</span>";
```

Try these points, please